# Using Autobahn/Twisted to establish a websocket connection in Tornado HTTP Handler

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, tornado, autobahn

Problem: 
Client sends in a http request. For that HTTP request, I want my tornado server to open a websocket connection to an external server and get some data overtime.(That data I need to store in the database). I also need to be able to handle multiple user requests to the tornado server.

Here's my implementation

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.write("This is your response")
        factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:7096")
        factory.protocol = BridgeSocket
        connectWS(factory)
        self.finish()
        reactor.run()
```

And here's my Socket connection class:

```
class BridgeSocket(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def sendHello(self):
        self.sendMessage("rails")

    def onOpen(self):
        self.sendHello()

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        print "Got echo: " + msg

    def onClose(wasClean,code,reason):
        print "GETTING CLOSE CONNECTION"
        print str(wasClean)+" ---"+str(code)+"---"+str(reason)
        reactor.stop()
```

Here reactor.run() prevents further http requests to the Tornado web server, so I tried reactor.stop() as soon as the websocket work is done and is closed. But now I found out that it is not possible restart reactor.

Is there any better alternative for the approach or anything I might be missing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the WebSocket client from AutobahnPython *under* Tornado, you need the Twisted-Tornado integration ("Twisted on Tornado") - see [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/twisted.html). This runs a Twisted reactor loop within Tornado.

Comment: thanks. works perfect. I have another question. I want my external server(Tornado) to be able to handle multiple websocket connections. I am using self.producer_queue.join() in onMessage() on my external server which blocks the IOLoop and prevents another connection until the queue has finished.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Tornado, so I don't know. You might want to ask a separate question tagged only `tornado` etc so you get attention ..